# Why is the shading off?

Tags: mesh, shaders

I'm making a spaceship type thing and there's this strange triangle that's lighter than the rest of that side of the ship. I haven't applied any materials yet and I'm certain the whole side is flat. Even when I delete the sphere shape it appears. What's going on?

[image: You can see the problem here. That whole side is supposed to be flat. Why is there that weird triangle that's lighter?]
[image: This is about the same perspective but in Edit mode.]

[image]

Comment: Third shape in from the bottom left has 5 vertices - that's what's causing your shading issue.

Comment: It does look like it has five vertices! It's actually a vertex behind it that looks like it's part of the shape. The shape only has four vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell conclusively without looking at your mesh.

Possible reasons for this kind of shading artifact are:

- You may have a non-planar quad. (where not all the vertices that make up the quad are on the same plane)
- You may have an n-gon. (despite from the screenshot it looks like a quad)

In either case adding a **Weighted Normal** modifier to your object should fix the problem.  However if you would like to go a bit deeper into this I would suggest first identifying the issue. (you can share your blend file here, we can take a look)

- If the issue is having a non-planar face (quad), there is a **Flatten** command. (you can go into edit mode and press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search.)
- If the issue is having an n-gon, selecting the face in edit mode should tell you in the status bar how many vertices it has.  Probably there are two vertices very close to each other due to boolean operation.

Comment: Thanks! It was the non-planar face. That was pretty subtle.